# Restrict Alertbox/Pop-up to inidvdual module in flex 3

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, flex3

I am trying to restrict a Alert-box to a specific module, it should not scope outside the module. I have kept to 2 tabs containing different modules in each. But the scope of alert is being global, and it is effecting the whole window other than limiting to the module area.
Please look at below code.

main.mxml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<mx:Application xmlns:mx="http://www.adobe.com/2006/mxml" layout="absolute">
<mx:Script>
    <![CDATA[
          import mx.modules.*;

         public function createModule(m:ModuleLoader, s:String):void {
        if (!m.url) {
            m.url = s;
            return;
        }
        m.loadModule();
    }

    public function removeModule(m:ModuleLoader):void {
        m.unloadModule();
    }


    ]]>
</mx:Script>
 <mx:Panel title="Module Example" 
    height="90%" 
    width="90%" 
    paddingTop="10" 
    paddingLeft="10" 
    paddingRight="10" 
    paddingBottom="10"
 >
    <mx:TabNavigator id="tn" 
        width="100%" 
        height="100%" 
        creationPolicy="auto">
        <mx:VBox id="vb1" label="Column Chart Module">                
            <mx:Button 
                label="Load"   click="createModule(chartModuleLoader, l1.text)"/>
            <mx:Button 
                label="Unload" />
            <mx:Label id="l1" text="module1.swf"/>
            <mx:ModuleLoader id="chartModuleLoader"/>                                
        </mx:VBox>

        <mx:VBox id="vb2" label="Form Module">
            <mx:Button 
                label="Load"    click="createModule(formModuleLoader, l2.text)"/>
            <mx:Button 
                label="Unload"/>
            <mx:Label id="l2" text="module2.swf"/>
            <mx:ModuleLoader id="formModuleLoader"/>
        </mx:VBox>
    </mx:TabNavigator>
</mx:Panel>
</mx:Application>
```

Module1.mxml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<mx:Module xmlns:mx="http://www.adobe.com/2006/mxml" layout="absolute" width="400"    height="300">
<mx:Button label="Click 1 " click="ini()"/>
<mx:Script>
    <![CDATA[
        import mx.controls.Alert;

        public function ini():void
        {
            Alert.show("How","hello", 0,null,null,null,0);
        }

    ]]>
</mx:Script>
</mx:Module>
```

Module2.mxml

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <mx:Module xmlns:mx="http://www.adobe.com/2006/mxml" layout="absolute" width="400" height="300">
<mx:Button label="Click 2 " click="ini1()"/>
<mx:Script>
    <![CDATA[
        import mx.controls.Alert;

        public function ini1():void
        {
            Alert.show("Click 2","hello", 0,this);
        }

    ]]>
</mx:Script>
 </mx:Module>
```

Thank You

Comment: That's how Alert.show works.  It creates an Alert at the root application level.  The only thing specifying "parent" does is tell flex what to center the alert on. If you want an alert that vanishes when you change tabs to another module and is only visible when the module is visible (I think this is what you are after), then you will need to create a custom component that looks like an alert that you can overlay with code instead of using the Alert class.

Comment: Can you Provide me a small custom class as example, so that i can get a better idea to start. Thanks in advance.

Comment: now that I think about this a little more, you could probably use PopUpManager. I'll provide code in an answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Per my comment, what you were trying wouldn't work.. but here is a way to accomplish it:

in each module that can display an alert:

```
private function createAlert(text:String):void{
    var myAlert:Alert = new Alert();
    myAlert.addEventListener(CloseEvent.CLOSE, onClose);
    myAlert.title = "Attention";
    myAlert.label = text;
    alertLayer.addElement(myAlert);
}

private function onClose(event:CloseEvent):void{
    trace("closed");
}
```

then in the module mxml

```
<s:VGroup id="alertLayer" width="100%" height="100%" verticalAlign="middle" horizontalAlign="center" />
```

This will force the alert in the topmost layer of the module without using PopUpManager or global scope at all.  Is this more of what you were after?

Comment: I dont think it will fix my original problem, but thanks for taking your time and showing the right path.

Comment: Here, I'll edit the answer to show you how to confine them using the actual Alert class

Comment: Hello Jason Reeves, 
That is what i was exactly looking for, you have given me the right point of working of alert local to module. Thank You

Comment: Hello @Jason Reeves , You have given me the right code, but there was an error encountered when i executed. The error pointed to  " popupmanagerImpl.as " . I thought i would solve that problem, but i was unable to do it. Can you resolve it. Thanks

Comment: I ran that code before I posted it and it worked fine.  So must be something else in your code that is causing it. Looks like you still have a reference to PopUpManager that you don't need?  Not sure.